# Problem in my solution "Repeated string match"

Tags: java, string

I have to tell the minimum number of times string `A` needs to be repeated so that string `B` becomes a substring of `A`.

My answer is wrong for some test cases like

```
A = "abc"
B = "cabcabca"
```

My output is coming 3..it should be 4.

My code is-

```
class Solution {
    public int repeatedStringMatch(String A, String B) {
        int count = 0;
        while (A.length() <= 1000) {
            if (A.indexOf(B) != -1)
                return (count + 1);
            else
                A = A + A;
            count++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of `A=A+A;` as it makes `A` as `abcabc` after the first iteration, `abcabcabcabc` after the second iteration, `abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc` after the third iteration and so on i.e. instead of getting appended, the string is getting doubled in each iteration.

It is like you have been given a task to add `2` to itself in each iteration i.e. after the first iteration, it should become `2 + 2 = 4`, after the second iteration, it should become `4 + 2 = 6`, after the third iteration it should become `6 + 2 = 8` and so on.

Whereas the way you have done, it will become `2 + 2 = 4` after the first iteration, `4 + 4 = 8` after the second iteration, `8 + 8 = 16` after the third iteration and so on.

As a side note, you should avoid using string concatenation in a loop. You should also follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the variable name `A` should be `a`.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test 
        System.out.println(repeatedStringMatch("abc", "cabcabca"));
    }

    static int repeatedStringMatch(String a, String b) {
        int count = 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a);
        while (sb.length() <= 1000) {
            if (sb.indexOf(b) != -1) {
                return count;
            } else {
                sb.append(a);
                count++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
```